# OS X El Capitan - Issues with OpenVPN and the .ovpn file extension

Tags: macos, openvpn, file-extension, osx-el-capitan

I'd like to set up an OpenVPN connection, but it just doesn't want to work. `.ovpn` files seem to be treated in a very special and odd way by OS X:

- When downloading `.ovpn` files, they're automatically renamed to `.ovpn.txt`
- When extracting an archive with an `.ovpn` file in it, I get a `permission denied` error and I'll have to extract all other files explicitly and via Terminal
- Double clicking on `.ovpn` files has no effect, even with Tunnelblick installed

It's a freshly installed OS X El Capitan 10.11.1 with Xcode and the Command Line Tools installed. The strange behaviour of `.ovpn` files was already present *before* I installed Tunnelblick.

Someone has an idea what this could be?

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be related to System Integrity Protection (SIP) with El Capitan. On solution may be to disable SIP and see if it works properly.
https://miteshshah.github.io/mac/how-to-solve-openvpn-problem-in-os-x-el-capitan/